# Random bug with webpack-encore in symfony and encoding

Tags: symfony, webpack, character-encoding, webpack-encore

I have a random problem with webpack-encore in symfony. When i refresh my page, i have an issue :

> "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Warning: htmlentities(): charset `throwAt' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8")."

I refresh and i have :

> "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Warning: htmlentities(): charset `handler' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8")."

I refresh and my page is good.

And it's a loop... (so weird !)

On others pages i don't see a loop. If i refresh, maybe work, maybe don't.

I have make some test. If i change this line in the TagRenderer.php (function : convertArrayToAttributes; line 114) :

> return sprintf('%s="%s"', $key, htmlentities($value));

with :

> return sprintf('%s="%s"', $key, htmlentities($value, ENT_COMPAT |
>   ENT_HTML401, "ISO8859-1"));

That work all the time. But I'm not sure that's the good solutions.

When i dump the "$value" before the line "htmlentities($value)", the value is : "stylesheet".

When i restart my computer, this issue disapear but with time, it's recome !

Do you have any idea ?

For informations : 
I'm on a docker image.
My source code are in UTF-8

Edit: Obviously, i clean the cache (via command or delete folder) before, after and between refresh but nothing change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error\_log flooded by "charset not supported, assuming utf-8" messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659640/error-log-flooded-by-charset-not-supported-assuming-utf-8-messages)

Comment: Thanks for that, i test this tonight. "internal_encoding utf-8" in php.ini. And check the log file size when i have this issue.

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb, one month later and all is ok with add in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I myself drooled for two days to try to solve this problem. In fact this is where you make the text edit in **CKEditor** that poses this problem.

While testing different things, I realized that we need to add `|` raw, and in the `convertArrayToAttributes` method of the `TagRenderer` class, instead of:

```
return sprintf ('%s = "%s"', $key, htmlentities ($value));
```

rather do:

```
return sprintf('%s = "%s"', $key, htmlentities($value, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_XHTML, 'utf-8'));
```